# Google Sign-in authentication can't enable

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebase-console

I'm trying to configure Firebase Auth for Google signin, butI got stuck. I don't understand what to do and how, as I have already configured and linked the firebase to my project. I have already downloaded and paste the google services file and also provided the SHA-1 key to the firebase setup.

Below is the screenshot of problem

[image]

I tried to configure google signin provider, but it shows this dialogue box that can't enable google signin for some apps